# Matplotlib label y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to build a chart using matplotlib but unfortunately I cannot figure it out how to label the y axis. I want to do this starting from 0.1 to 1.0 with a 0.1 difference.
I managed to set its limits like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 N = 10
 menMeans = (0.58836, 0.6224, 0.73047, 0.79147, 0.79284, 0.79264, 0.79922, 0.82043, 0.81834, 0.74767)

 ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
 width = 0.20       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='g')

womenMeans = (0.61139, 0.62270, 0.63627, 0.75868, 0.73087, 0.73128, 0.77205, 0.59866, 0.59385, 0.59891)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='b')

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('Naive', 'Norm', 'Unigrams \n(FreqDist)', 'Unigrams(LLR)', 'Unigrams (LLR)\n Bigrams', 'Unigrams (LLR)\n Bigrams (CHI)',
         'Unigrams (LLR)\n Bigrams (LLR)', 'Features', 'POS', 'LDA') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Naive Bayes', 'Maximum Entropy') )
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

but numbers on y axis show up only with a 0.2 difference. Any solution for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.set_ylim(0.1, 1)
import matplotlib.ticker as tick
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tick.MultipleLocator(0.1))
```